# Trying to reuse MFC dll in a WPF C# application

Tags: c#, wpf, mfc

I have a DLL that exposes a COM interface. I have used it in the past in a simple MFC Dialog application.
I need to reuse that DLL in a WPF application (using C#). I have been trying to use the DllImport directive to no avail.
I have boiled it down to a very simple project but I still cannot get it to run.

```
// MFC dll header
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Worker.h"

Worker::Worker(void)
{
}

Worker::~Worker(void)
{
}

int Worker::GetInteger()
{
    return 44;
}

//WPF code
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        [DllImport("C:\\Users\\mspath\\Documents\\MDS_SIMCA\\DevSIMCA_Dll\\TestDLL\\Debug\\MFCLib.dll", 
                 EntryPoint = "?GetInteger@Worker@@SAHXZ",
                 ExactSpelling=false, 
                 SetLastError=true, 
                 CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
        //public static extern void CreateSIMCAProj(bool bBatch, System.String csFilePath, System.String csProjName);
        public extern static int GetInteger();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int iTest = GetInteger();
        }
    }
```

The error I get when I run it, NO matter if I have the correct dll name listed is..

"Invalid PInvoke calling convention. Thiscall requires that the first parameter is present and can be enregistered."

I ran the dumpbin.exe utility on the dll to get that long function name, no matter how I change that line though I still get the same error.

Comment: That's an instance function.  You need an instance.

Comment: "ThisCall" means it's a non-static function, needing an instance. So your "GetInteger()" declaration needs a 'this' parameter. GetInteger(IntPtr _this);

Comment: Just changing the argument to .Cdecl, it now works

Comment: I'm trying to simply build on the simple example I created. Just adding another method to the mfclib.dll does not work I get an entry point not found error {"Unable to find an entry point named '?GetAnotherInteger@Worker@@SAHXZ' in DLL <path>  
namespace WpfApplicationTest